# developer warning for package android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, developer-tools

I tried to add Notification to my app and when i wrote the following code:

it show this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxZQ1.png
[the Message it show when i click the Button, i don't know if its a Toast message][1]

```
 package com.example.notifsimple

import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val id = 1234

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnNotif.setOnClickListener{

            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android)
                .setContentTitle("New Animal")
                .setContentText("a new ")
                .build()


            val mNotificationCompat = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            mNotificationCompat.notify(id, notification)

        }

    }
}
```

'''`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNotif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notification"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks for reading my Question. <3

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is used for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [platform source](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java?q=%22developer%20warning%22), this toast is shown when the notification channel comes out as null.

Looking at your source, there is no notification channel. Starting from Android 8.0 (API 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels) for more info.

Comment: i added                      val CHNANNEL_ID = "channel_01"     AND  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)                             AND                                                       val mChannel = NotificationChannel(CHNANNEL_ID, "اسم القناة", importance)                                   val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
 
            mNotificationManager.notify(id, notification)                  "still the same problem"